# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 in my pod classes

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, x86-64

I updated my pods. After the update I am not able to launch my app due to following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DownPicker", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in ChooseBookViewController.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKAppEvents", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in AnalyticsProvider.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKApplicationDelegate", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Mixpanel", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in AnalyticsProvider.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PHFComposeBarView", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in ForumBaseVC.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKDynamicMapping", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in WikiArticle.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKObjectManager", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in MLDataProvider.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKObjectMapping", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in WikiError.o
          objc-class-ref in WikiArticle.o
          objc-class-ref in WikiLogin.o
          objc-class-ref in WikiQuery.o
          objc-class-ref in Model.o
          objc-class-ref in WikiThumbnail.o
          objc-class-ref in MLError.o
```

[image]

How do I solve this?

Regards

Comment: Try to add $(inherited) to Other Linker Flags,Framework Search Paths, Library Search Paths, clean and build.

Comment: already have $(inherited) to all the alternatives mentioned :/